# How to find all ES6+ features applied in a big JS project

Tags: babeljs

Is there some way to search or profile all js code in a react-project, to find all ES6+ features used in it?

Recently I've upgraded to Babel 7,4+ and it's doc suggests to only polyfill the features that are used in a project. I've tried using core-js-compat, but it lists all features based on browserlist support settings.

And in a best case scenario, I would like to set each polyfill separately, as:

```js
require('core-js/[used-feature-1]');
require('core-js/[used-feature-2]');
require('core-js/[used-feature-N]');
```